# Converting a generic React Component to TypeScript throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-ref

I am trying to port https://github.com/catalinmiron/react-typical to TypeScript. However, I am facing some issues.

Here's the screenshot with errors in VSCode:

[image: TS project in VSCode]

Here's the same code for brevity:

```
import React from 'react'
import { type, type as loopedType } from '@camwiegert/typical'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

type Props = {
    steps: Array<any>
    loop: number
    className: string
    wrapper: React.Component
}

const Typical: React.FC<Props> = ({ steps, loop, className, wrapper = 'p' }) => {
    const typicalRef = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null)
    const Component: string = wrapper
    const classNames: string[] = [styles.typicalWrapper]

    if (className) {
        classNames.unshift(className)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (loop === Infinity) {
            type(typicalRef.current, ...steps, loopedType)
        } else if (typeof loop === 'number') {
            type(typicalRef.current, ...Array(loop).fill(steps).flat())
        } else {
            type(typicalRef.current, ...steps)
        }
    }, [typicalRef])

    return <Component ref={typicalRef} className={classNames.join(' ')} />
}

export default React.memo(Typical)
```

I am unable to write type for `Component`.

I tried doing the following too:

```
const Component = React.Component | string
```

But it says `'Component' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Component'?` near `return <Component .../>` with underline over `Component`.

I am also unable to convert the `typicalRef` as `typicalRef.current` always throws error by showing red squiggly lines under it. Same thing with `flat()` as well as `classNames.join(' ')`.

I am losing my brain over it. Can't seem to figure it out. Would love any pointers?

Comment: What are the errors shown by VSCode? Also if you just want to ignore them without actually fixing them, add a `// @ts-ignore` above the lines (although you should try to fix them, of course).

Comment: have you tried renaming the variable Component to something else?

Comment: @EmreKoc the 1st error on Component is written in the post. Read the line just below `const Component = React.Component | string`. I'd love to solve it rather than ignoring it.

Comment: @FaisalRashid there is no need to rename it something else as neither `Component` is a reserved keyword or I am destructuring `Component` from `react` itself so I think it should be fine even if I rename it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't solve it using directly as I think TypeScript itself doesn't support it https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28892

But I did solve it using `React.createElement` syntax. My entire code looks like this right now:

```
import React from 'react'
import { type, type as loopedType } from '@camwiegert/typical'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

type Props = {
    steps: Array<any>
    loop: number
    className?: string
    wrapper: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>

const Typical = ({ steps, loop, className, wrapper: Wrapper = 'p' }: Props) => {
    const typicalRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement> = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null)
    const classNames: string[] = [styles.typicalWrapper]

    if (className) {
        classNames.unshift(className)
    }

    const typicalStyles: string = classNames.join(' ')

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (loop === Infinity) {
            type(typicalRef.current as HTMLElement, ...steps, loopedType)
        } else if (typeof loop === 'number') {
            type(typicalRef.current as HTMLElement, ...Array(loop).fill(steps).flat())
        } else {
            type(typicalRef.current as HTMLElement, ...steps)
        }
    }, [typicalRef])

    return React.createElement(Wrapper, {
        ref: typicalRef,
        className: typicalStyles,
    })
}

export default React.memo(Typical)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Component part, set it in the props instead of a new variable:

```js
const Typical: React.FC<Props> = ({ wrapper:Component = 'p' }) => {
    return <Component />
}
```

Comment: I've done that already in `Props`. See the `type Props` definition. I don't understand what is the difference between my code & yours?

Comment: Yours is setting the type of prop, mine is renaming the prop from wrapper to Component, so you can use it as a tag. Basically what you tried to do with the const, without the const.

Comment: Ohh got it. But it still gives me error on the `return <Component />` saying `'Component' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Component'?ts(2749)`

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969769/typing-a-dynamic-tag-in-react-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set your `wrapper` to `React.ComponentType<React.PropsWithRef<any>>` which is accurate React type and rename your wrapper directly (do not re-assign in the body that `tsc` can be confused with mixed type as string) so your code might change as following:

```
type Props = {
 steps: Array<any>
 loop: number
 className: string
 wrapper: React.ComponentType<React.PropsWithRef<any>>
}

const Typical: React.FC<Props> = ({ steps, loop, className, wrapper: Component = 'p' }) => {
  const typicalRef = React.useRef<HTMLElement>()
  const classNames: string[] = [styles.typicalWrapper]

  if (className) {
    classNames.unshift(className)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loop === Infinity) {
        type(typicalRef.current, ...steps, loopedType)
    } else if (typeof loop === 'number') {
        type(typicalRef.current, ...Array(loop).fill(steps).flat())
    } else {
        type(typicalRef.current, ...steps)
    }
  }, [typicalRef]) 

  return <Component ref={typicalRef} className={classNames.join(' ')} />
}
```

Since `flat` method is only available from "es2019" which means you have to include it in the the `tsc` build by adding to the `tsconfig.json` following:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": ["ES2019"]
},
```

Comment: So the `flat()` thing worked but I still get the other 3 errors sadly. I did exactly as u said.

Comment: What are the 3 others?

Comment: the 1st one is the one on the `Component`, then `typicalRef.current` says `Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2345)` & finally on `className={classNames.join(' ')}` it says `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` on `className` & on `classNames` it says `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)`

Comment: Does it appear after you have changed based on my suggestion? If so, can I see your fully edited code again?

Comment: I've just edited to show full my suggestion. You can copy & double check again if your errors get disappeared?

Comment: It doesn't work haha. I think its a Typescript issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28892

Comment: I solved it by using `React.createElement` instead. I'll post an answer :)