# React + TS: Using generic types to get HTML props based on tag name

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, generics

I have a common use case where I want a component that is simply a styled HTML tag. For example, the following works fine for creating style divs:

```
// Definitions
const styledDiv = (className: string) => {
    const StyledDiv = React.FC<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> => props => {
        return <div {...props} className={classNames(className, props.className)} />;
    }

    return StyledDiv;
}

// Usage
const Foo = styledDiv(styles.foo);

const Bar = () => {
    return <Foo className={styles.bar} onClick={...} ... />
}
```

I am attempting to make this generic so that it will work for any HTML element, not just divs. I have tried the following:

```
// Definition
export const styledTag = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(className: string, tag: T) => {
    const Tag = tag;

    const StyledTag: React.FC<HTMLAttributes<T>> = props => {
        const classes = classNames(className, props.className);
        return <Tag {...props} className={classes}/>;  
    };

    return StyledTag;
};

// Desired usage:
const Foo = styledTag(styles.foo, 'div');

const Bar = styledTag(styles.bar, 'span');

const Baz = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Foo ... />
            <Bar ... />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a `Type X is not assignable to type Y` error when I try to spread my props on the tag (`<Tag {...props} />`). Is there a way to accomplish this generically, or will I have to repeat this code for every HTML tag I want?

Comment: Couldn't you just implement it for `HTMLElement`, the base for all HTML Elements?

Comment: I don't know if that is an improvment from what you did, but I did [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2asdz4?file=src%2FApp.tsx). I still have a warning, but it works and autocompletion works too

Comment: Please check this question and answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969769/typing-a-dynamic-tag-in-react-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works - comments inline (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkFsAcBsEsDG8Aup4wPYCcUGdQBDAOwBNRSBTaSs25SvAWACgNoc0AlSwxNAGbZMkUACJsvfmIDcrdp1AoAnjVABvUAAkAKgFkAMgEEUKbPABGAVxSNQAX1BCR4yXxSzWVRLEKSnVsT88JjEoD6EeHgAcoSQjAAUAHQpfgDmeABcRMTKANoAugCU2STKGvZyLN6+-oiheGiNyrCMpblVrCCgACKUAvDEqCHErJQAHhy44Q1NKq2kOoRpoAC8oAA8OqATtmQEANaUypgCoABSAMoAGkngxGaDeEgAoq3xD3gAfAmsoOG+KKxeLZRrmYhpAA0fyUy2yOlYRTWXw0MPqxEaoCWK3WKGWnRY-3RmMu80oizhoB47iSADEAMIbXSGEyPay2PBbL4o9YJaDCaB4JGrFHqGFE2YAyJ4OzrCJAuKJeUxRWQ0D8zCCpLK4GUIpVf7-bo6AAW8AIAHd4LBYKALTgDk5BpRMuLQJIUFZsGFqfxtW5bG9KB8UAlsWrNCkkhrBWqdYrssq7PZ9aw3cazZbrbaUCbhBacjtsMJsDsAG60O2oE2YGygPD83ikQYrGMEULoFCuwmG7oer1hLbLUDAL4Ew0jsCm83oAgWSiIQhWGWgU71kSUJwkRDKYAmvgHcq5lsENKYFursKDUAAARUNDwwDc-By5Cu13TU5Nm6oAyGKBGAgBBwC4bnrZQHkIcZQGIShySUTBQH3MhWlACxMFzcJlxQFx6iwWDPlABJc0INB5zSa8rUwwhwkIaBUEIW1WlMShsCKaEeyNMASHIE0UEgHNlgIYj9zIygKLCKiTSIUBYEwC1WMXFdmNsNikixb9JAAcgIGi5LQNdBmbSRglCNV2QgJQzWIR1SJks00mk1oK1gT9Ox0mCMKICxUJwpRKBtKy7LEbExFAABaKtMNzTcLUIcoTisLSKwofpnXIGLQDSWhWKQAhIpndwrEY2ByhIbR9AMWE0iSGFKjTHt+29UBSRaclsSqeqWC6MA+meSRyGXZYXVYYk0FpTBEPWZoFmxBIZsYJJgMwNUxGbMsxFTbqWDG0AACE-DWesyQpNJ5rJPAkgsPxVobEhNoJXaDoALyOhJhVFGEmrCX5OM2davjdf4NgmxDRyBzYDtLcG-o2YAAZhLauqAA)):

```
// Implicit imports and dependencies
import React from "react";
import type { HTMLAttributes } from "react";
declare function classNames(...args: any[]): any {};
declare const styles: any;

// Definition
export const styledTag = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(
  className: string,
  tag: T
) => {
  const Tag = tag;

  const StyledTag: React.FC<HTMLAttributes<T>> = (props) => {
    const classes = classNames(className, props.className);
    // This will work fine:
    return React.createElement(Tag, { ...props, className: classes });

    // This will throw an error even without spreading props on it:
    // return <Tag />;

    // This is because of some fancy/hacky things going on in @types/react and JSX.
    // The definitions for JSX syntax need to handle both custom components (that begin with a capital letter),
    // and html tags (that begin with a lowercase letter). There's a lot of indirection, but I think at a high level
    // it's not able to tell that "Tag" - with the way you've defined the generics - is actually an HTML tag.
  };

  return StyledTag;
};

// Desired usage:
const Foo = styledTag(styles.foo, "div");

const Bar = styledTag(styles.bar, "span");

const Baz = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Foo />
      <Bar />
    </div>
  );
};
```