# How to do TypeScript type with React if passing element as tag string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the cleanest/proper way to do something like this?

```
import React, { HTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import c from 'classnames'
import styles from './index.module.css'

export type ComponentProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> & {
  tag?: string
  className?: string
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

function Component({
  className,
  tag = 'div',
  children,
}: ComponentProps): React.ReactElement {
  const Element = tag
  return (
    <Element className={c(className, styles.v)}>{children}</Element>
  )
}

export default Component
```

Basically, I want to pass `tag` attribute as a string (the native HTML tag), but then have it accept the attributes of that tag type. So if I pass `tag = 'a'`, then `Element extends HTMLAnchorElement`, sort of thing. How do I properly accomplish this in React/TypeScript?

Comment: Could you show an example of usage? You mean you want `Component` to also accept the props corresponding to the `tag`? What if `tag` is a `string` that's **not** an element name?

Comment: I simply want to pass a `tag` property to a headless `Component`, and have it render the appropriate tag. This is as isolated as an example as it can get. This works fine without TypeScript, now I am trying to make it work with TypeScript.

Comment: That doesn't answer @jonrsharpe's question. Do you want `Component` to accept props specific to the type of HTML element? Currently you don't seem to show it doing that (no rest element in the props destructuring, no spread on `<Element .../>`). Or do you just want what you have above to work from a types perspective? (His request for usage examples is also perfectly reasonable.)

Comment: What's currently _not_ working would also be helpful - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55969769/3001761 is probably at least part of what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to have type safety with your approach.

As an alternative, you could use a Factory pattern as described [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/extendable-factory-pattern-for-react-using-typescript-3298c59fefd8), which is much more complicated and requires you to define, which kind of components you can instantiate dynamically - but from a perspective of robustness and security this is maybe what you would want to do anyway.