# React Dynamic Tag Name Using TypeScript Generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, polymorphism, jsx

I have a simple polymorphic React component that is supposed to only render tag names (e.g. `span`) but *not* render custom React components (e.g. `MyComponent`). It looks like this can be achieved using `JSX.IntrinsicElements`. I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";

type PolymorphicComponentProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = {
  as?: T;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T];

const PolymorphicComponent = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = "div">({
  as: Component = "div" as T,
  ...rest
}: PolymorphicComponentProps<T>) => {
  return <Component {...rest} />; // TS error: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
};
```

The generic type `T` will determine the HTML attributes that are available. For example, if I were to render `PolymorphicComponent` as an `a` tag...

```
<PolymorphicComponent as="a" />
```

...then I would get autocomplete for the `href` attribute/prop. And as another example, if I were to render `PolymorphicComponent` as an `img` tag...

```
<PolymorphicComponent as="img" />
```

...then I would get autocomplete for the `src` attribute/prop. This appears to be working as expected, but I am still dealing with the TypeScript error that is commented in the `PolymorphicComponent` component function definition: `JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures`.

**What I can't figure out:** The `Component` variable (alias for the `as` prop) has a type of `T | (T & string)`. I would expect the type of `Component` to just be `T`.

If I create this very simple component that *always* renders a `div`, there are no TypeScript errors:

```
const DivComponent = () => {
  const Div: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = "div";
  return <Div />;
};
```

**Question:** What do I need to change in order to get rid of the TypeScript error? From what I've read, I don't need to replace the JSX with `React.createElement` so I'm looking to keep the JSX version of this component if possible.

Comment: Even if you do somehow find a way, you would still get this error whose size rivals with the Burj Khalifa: https://tsplay.dev/NdYRkm. To be honest, I think casting like this is the easiest method of solving it anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I'm super curious to know if there's a better way, but here's what I came up with; long story short, if you cast `Component` to `React.ElementType` then TS is happy:

```
type IntrinsicElement = keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;

type PolymorphicComponentProps<T extends IntrinsicElement> = {
  as?: T;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T];

const PolymorphicComponent = <T extends IntrinsicElement = 'div'>({
  as: elementType = 'div' as T,
  ...rest
}: PolymorphicComponentProps<T>) => {
  const Component = elementType as ElementType;
  return <Component {...rest} />;
};
```

Comment: Good thought! What's interesting is if you instead do `const Component: ElementType = elementType;`, there is an error related to `SVGProps<SVGSymbolElement>`. For my particular use-case, asserting that `elementType` is `React.Element` and ignoring the potential `SVGProps<SVGSymbolElement>` issue is more than good enough, but thought I'd point it out for others.

Comment: * Instead of "asserting that elementType is React.Element," I mean to say "casting elementType as React.ElementType"

Comment: Made one without casting the type, though it's slightly longer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76178335/16649797