# React custom Button component "as" prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, react-bootstrap

I want to add a feature to my Button component wherein I want to add an `as` prop just like in other component libraries to render different components based on the `as` value.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing a dynamic tag in React with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969769/typing-a-dynamic-tag-in-react-with-typescript)

Comment: this is not about typing a tag

Comment: Yeah I know, but did you even read that post I linked? Yes the **title** is about typing the tag, but the actual case in the question is using a component prop (in that case called `tag`) to determine what kind of element/component to render, which is what you're asking for your `as` use case

Comment: it is like the react-bootstrap's Button component wherein you can pass a component as a prop say as={HashLink} then HashLink will be rendered instead of button (by default). See https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/

Comment: Check out this article: [Build strongly typed polymorphic components with React and TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-strongly-typed-polymorphic-components-react-typescript/)